# Can ajax give me the data size on the URL?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'v been using the progress event, and b.c. it can track this, I was wondering if the xjr object has access to the total data size in KB or MB or similar?

FYI here is my code

```
var container = Pub.el('#super-1');
if (container) {
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            // Pub.log(config_ajax.url);
            var percent = ( evt.loaded / evt.total ) * 100;
            var exists = document.getElementById(config_ajax.url)
            if(exists){
                Pub.log('div exists');
                exists.style.width = percent + '%';
            } else {
                Pub.log('div created');
                var div = document.createElement('div');
                div.id=config_ajax.url;
                div.style.width = percent + '%';
                div.style.height = '5px';
                div.style.background = 'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)';
                div.style.borderBottom = '1px solid white';
                container.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
    }, false);
}
return xhr;
```

};

Comment: Seems like it's *possible* if the response includes a `Content-Length` header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Servers **may** provide the length of content in the optional [`content-length` header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.13). You can read it, if available with `getResponseHeader`.

Comment: At what stage can you read that? If you have to wait to the point where the request is received, that doesn't seem super-useful.

Comment: @Pointy — You can read it as soon as the response headers have been received, which will be relatively quickly in a response which it is going to take long enough to be worth tracking progress events.

Comment: so is that something that happens at some particular `readyState`? Or do you have to poll it or something? (Asking because I've never heard of the ability to do this, though as I commented above it certainly seems like it could be possible.)

Comment: ...I'm making a graphic while my page loads - width percentage is the progress percentage ... and I want height to be the file size.  I could calculate this on the server, but if it was on the xhr object the code would be much cleaner.

Comment: https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-xmlhttprequest-readystate — The `HEADERS_RECEIVED` readyState will fire when the headers have been recieved.